Can the Simple Java Mail Mailer instance be reused? Is it thread safe?
I need some clarification about the usage of Mailer class of the Simple Java Mail library, after creating a Mailer instance like:
Mailer mailer = MailerBuilder.withSMTPServer(
        smtpHost,
        smtpPort,
        smtpUser,
        smtpPassword
    ).
    withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTPS).
    buildMailer();

I send email with mailer.sendEmail(email).
Can the Mailer instance be reused to send multiple mails? Or I have to create one for every email I want to send? Right now I tested and it seems to be OK to send multiple emails but not sure.
Is it thread safe?

Please specify what the Mailer library is.

@MarkRotteveel it's in the title, it's named Simple Java Mail. https://www.simplejavamail.org/  , I wrote Simple Java Mail library

Thanks, I hadn't interpreted that as name, but just descriptive. Your questions are answered by its documentation: Configure once, reuse many times and Asynchronous parallel batch sending and clustering

If you have a use case where really to worry about, if something is thread safe or not, you should assume it is not. If you really have an issue, then look into the source (of your version). Btw I cannot find Mailer (but MailerBuilder) in the last version of this lib.

@MarkRotteveel  thanks for your clarification. If you will answer it I will accept it. I read the javadoc https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail/latest/index.html (here the is not Mailer but I have the javadoc of this class in on my IDE) and it was not clear to me, I didn't pay the right attention if it was on the site

@PeterMmm yes on javadoc https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.simplejavamail/simple-java-mail/latest/index.html there is not Mailer class, I was reading it on my IDE (I don't know how but Intellij gives me the javadoc of Mailer too) and it was not clear to me. The doubt was because it implements AutoClosable

The javadoc of Mailer is in core-module, not simple-java-mail

The documentation of Simple Java Mail explicitly says you can create the mailer once and reuse it many times and that it's thread-safe, specifically the section Configure once, reuse many times:

You can preconfigure a Mailer and use it many times. It is thread-safe.

Additionally it provides forms of Asynchronous parallel batch sending and clustering, which further reinforces its thread-safety. Or at least, if something provides parallel batch sending, I would expect it to be thread-safe, even if it hadn't been declared explicitly.
